# Heroku deployment problems

Tags: node.js

so I'm having trouble deploying to heroku, everything runs fine locally, but on heroku I can't do anything, here is the error log :

```
2018-08-04T01:52:26.964898+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
2018-08-04T01:52:26.964900+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
2018-08-04T01:52:26.964902+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
2018-08-04T01:52:26.964903+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
2018-08-04T01:52:26.964905+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2018-08-04T01:52:26.966194+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2018-08-04T01:52:27.323128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-08-04T01:52:27.350046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-04T01:54:17.878013+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lavp24059100.herokuapp.com request_id=3a636b29-8f6b-4c02-925d-10e5bd3a35e6 fwd="142.169.78.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-08-04T02:55:09.482522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-08-04T02:55:25.444469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597135+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
2018-08-04T02:55:30.995570+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 40958
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597157+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597159+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597161+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597163+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597165+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597167+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597169+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597171+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597173+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
2018-08-04T02:55:30.597175+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2018-08-04T02:55:30.599023+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2018-08-04T02:55:31.092834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-08-04T02:55:31.111608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and here is the package.json :

```
{
  "name": "paradigme-internet-projet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
     "node": "4.2.6",
     "npm": "3.5.2"
   },
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
 "debug": "~2.6.9",
 "express": "~4.16.0",
 "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
 "mongodb": "2.0.14",
 "mongoose": "3.8.31",
 "haversine-distance": "1.1.0",
 "geolocation": "0.2.0",
 "node-geocoder": "3.22.0",
 "morgan": "~1.9.0",
 "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
 "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
 "raml2html": "^7.1.0"
 }
}
```

Yes I did try previously given answers, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the mongoose version of your

```
package.json
```

to the following :

```
"mongoose": "~4.4"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried it, it helped, I got rid of the BSON error however I still have :  2018-08-04T05:39:46.423661+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-04T05:39:46.230875+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/raml2obj/index.js:150
2018-08-04T05:39:46.230896+00:00 app[web.1]: function _sourceToRamlObj(source, options = {}) {

Comment: Can you please Edit your answer and paste the error at the bottom in a formatted way, I can't read the complete error from comment (Word limit pal ! )